# page.pdf() is much slower after upgrading from chromium 117 to 119

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

i have a cloud run that is an api for generating PDFs based on html input, i'm using `node:16-alpine`, `puppeteer`, `chromium` and it was running fine until alpine upgraded it's chromium package from `117.0.5938.62-r0` to `119.0.6045.159-r0` and execution time of the pdf function tripled.
i thought about setting chromium version to fixed in my Dockerfile but it's not allowed on alpine.
**any suggestions?**

Comment: You should probably report this as a Puppeteer bug.

Comment: already did https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/11494

Comment: issue is confirmed a bug. reported to chromium repo https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/11494#issuecomment-1850541040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quickest solution i could find is to downgrade alpine to `node:16-alpine3.17` instead of the current version `3.18` in my `Dockerfile` so that my chromium version would be `112.0.5615.165-r0`.
this solution based on my research was the safest since manually setting package versions can result in conflicts and a lot of overhead in the future